# Combining two pandas dataframes with just adding the integer count

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add two pandas dataframes of different lengths together:

```
    fruit rating  count
0  apple      A      2
1  pear       B      2
2  peach      A      1
3  apple      B      2
4  pear       C      1  

    fruit rating  count
0   apple       A    0
1   apple       B    0
2   apple       C    0
3   pear        A    0
4   pear        B    0
5   pear        C    0
6  peach        A    0
7  peach        B    0
8  peach        C    0
```

Basically i want to add the first dataframes' count integer to the second one below it where the type and rating are the same. For example, index 1 on dataframe1 should add a 2 two the count on index 4 of dataframe2 because of "pear and B".

I have tried the update function but it seems to mess with the index and just replaces the type and rating. Apologies if I am not proficient in explaining. I am still learning. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `groupby` on the relevant index:

```
temp1=first_df.set_index(['fruit','rating'])
temp2=second_df.set_index(['fruit','rating'])
result = temp1.add(temp2,fill_value=0)
```

This gives you a multiindexed `DataFrame`:

```
              count
fruit rating       
apple A         2.0
      B         2.0
      C         0.0
peach A         1.0
      B         0.0
      C         0.0
pear  A         0.0
      B         2.0
      C         1.0
```

If you want to remove the indexing just reset the index:

```
result.reset_index()
Out[182]: 
   fruit rating  count
0  apple      A    2.0
1  apple      B    2.0
2  apple      C    0.0
3  peach      A    1.0
4  peach      B    0.0
5  peach      C    0.0
6   pear      A    0.0
7   pear      B    2.0
8   pear      C    1.0
```

Comment: There's no need to groupby. Fruit and rating seems to be unique already. Use set index

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning myself. Actually this has helped me a lot in achieving what I thought `groupby` would do for me.

Answer (score 1):

I find SQL most intuitive for such purposes:

```
import pandasql
import pandas as pd

pysqldf = lambda q: pandasql.sqldf(q, globals())

Table1 = pd.DataFrame()
Table1['x'] = [x for x in range(10)]
Table2 = pd.DataFrame()
Table2['x'] = [x for x in range(10)]

print pysqldf('''
SELECT 
    *,
    1 as ID 
FROM Table1
UNION
    SELECT *,2 as ID 
    FROM Table2
''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframes are df1 and df2 respectively,

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how = 'outer', on = ['fruit', 'rating'])
df3 = df3.drop('count_x', axis = 1).fillna(0)
df3.columns = ['fruit', 'rating', 'count']
```

will give you the desired dataframe

```
fruit   rating  count
0   apple   A   2.0
1   apple   B   2.0
2   apple   C   0.0
3   pear    A   0.0
4   pear    B   2.0
5   pear    C   1.0
6   peach   A   1.0
7   peach   B   0.0
8   peach   C   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This focuses on updated just the rows that need to be added and preserving the `integer` `dtype`

```
df1.append(df2).groupby(['fruit', 'rating']).sum().reset_index()

   fruit rating  count
0  apple      A      2
1  apple      B      2
2  apple      C      0
3  peach      A      1
4  peach      B      0
5  peach      C      0
6   pear      A      0
7   pear      B      2
8   pear      C      1
```